# 415 Undocumented Error: Unsupported Media Type in asp.net core web api using multipart/formdata in [frombody]

Tags: asp.net-core

I have class model which I need to pass in my controller using multipart form data with `[frombody]`, but my api gives me

> error 415 unsupported media type in asp.netcore

```
   public class MedcoExpertModel
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ID")]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "NamePrefix")]
        public string NamePrefix { get; set; }
        public IFormFile Signaturefile { get; set; }
        public IFormFile CVfile { get; set; }
        public IFormFile AccCertificatefile { get; set; }
        public IFormFile Contractfile { get; set; }
        public IFormFile ICOfile { get; set; }
        public IFormFile Insurancefile { get; set; }
        public IFormFile MedcoCertificatefile { get; set; }


    }
```

and controller is

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
        [EnableCors("AllowOrigin")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<OutputWarapper<OutputData>>> AddMedcoExpert([FromBody] MedcoExpertModel medcomodel )
        {
            try
            {
                var sample = await _iexpert.AddMedcoExpert(medcomodel);
                
                return Ok(sample);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }
        }
```

if I used fromform instead of frombody.api method hit on method. but I need to pass the values using frombody with `multipart/formdata`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. if we used Multipart/farmdata then we  can used fromform instead formbody.and we can everything pass in the class model.